# How do I split a Dataframe column in two but taking into account that sometimes there is nothing to split and the value belongs to the second column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have:

```
          COLUMN A
0    00000-UNITED STATES
1    01000-ALABAMA
2    01001-Autauga County, AL
3    01003-Baldwin County, AL
4    Barbour County, AL
```

I want to split them in two columns but making sure that if the value in the last row is a string, it goes to the second column. If it's an int it goes to the first column. E.g with string:

```
          COLUMN B       COLUMN C
0          00000      UNITED STATES
1          01000         ALABAMA
2          01001     Autauga County, AL
3          01003     Baldwin County, AL
4                    Barbour County, AL
```

I tried this:

```
df[['B','C']] = df.A.str.split(" - ", n = 1, expand=True)
```

And it returned this obviously:

```
          COLUMN B       COLUMN C
0          00000      UNITED STATES
1          01000         ALABAMA
2          01001     Autauga County, AL
3          01003     Baldwin County, AL
4     Barbour County, AL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) and a regex to have the second capture group be the value after the optional `-`:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df['A'].str.extract(r"(\d+$|\d+(?=\s*-))?(?:\s*-\s*)?(.+)?")
```

```
                          A       B                   C
0       00000-UNITED STATES   00000       UNITED STATES
1             01000-ALABAMA   01000             ALABAMA
2  01001-Autauga County, AL   01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003-Baldwin County, AL   01003  Baldwin County, AL
4        Barbour County, AL     NaN  Barbour County, AL
5                     10234   10234                 NaN
6                32 Alabama     NaN          32 Alabama
7            432423 - state  432423               state
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['00000-UNITED STATES', '01000-ALABAMA',
          '01001-Autauga County, AL', '01003-Baldwin County, AL',
          'Barbour County, AL', '10234', '32 Alabama', '432423 - state']
})

df[['B', 'C']] = df['A'].str.extract(r"(\d+$|\d+(?=\s*-))?(?:\s*-\s*)?(.+)?")
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the response! Nonetheless if we apply your solution but we have a number instead of a string, it goes to the second column as well.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. So I need that when there is nothing to split. If it is an int it goes to the first column and when it is a string it goes to the second column.

Comment: Life saving! Thanks!

Comment: Found another "if"... In case I have something like '32 alabama', it splits the string anyways despite it does not have the correct delimiter. The correct behaviour should be to put it all on the second column, like if it was a string.

Comment: Worked for the  '32 alabama' but not for the regular values where we have like '432423 - state'

Comment: I totally understand and I'm sorry. It's actually my first time doing a such specific question. Despite that, thank you for the perseverance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two functions to extract the desired elements from COLUMN A and assign to COLUMN B and COLUMN C:

```
def get_col_b(item):
    if '-' in item:
        return item.split('-')[0]
    else:
        return ''

def get_col_c(item):
    if '-' in item:
        return item.split('-')[1]
    else:
        return item
```

Create the columns and then drop COLUMN A:

```
df['COLUMN B'] = df['COLUMN A'].apply(get_col_b)
df['COLUMN C'] = df['COLUMN A'].apply(get_col_c)
cols = ['COLUMN B', 'COLUMN C']
df = df[cols]
```

[image]